# Retag or Synonym SCVMMR2 -> SCVMM

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The R2 release of SCVMM isn't different enough to warrant it's own tag.
Also, it's the 2008 R2 version, so the tag name isn't even accurate to start.

The [scvmmr2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/scvmmr2) tag has more questions than [scvmm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/scvmm), so I can't propose the synonym*.

*Yet another reason the whole 'synonym proposal' system is borked.

Answer (score 1):

completed; thanks for the suggestion!